# Admob interstitial Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show."

Tags: ios, admob

> Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." 
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show.,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show.}

I tested the test Interstitial Ad Unit Id and my Interstitial Ad Unit Id with InterstitialExample app or my sample app and added all the targeting information and was able to load test Ads successfully.But it did't work with my application

Comment: did you add appId into appdelegate?

Comment: yes ,I have configured it into appdelegate.

Comment: did you add firebase pod OR google_mobile_ad_sdk?

Comment: add firebase pod.'Firebase/Core' and 'Firebase/AdMob'

Comment: Just clean project and run again. or check your Id again

Comment: have tried it but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add my Payment information and no ads were showing. After setting up payment info. Ads started to show and were working fine

Comment: I have fixed it. the season is that my app set User-Agent.

Comment: @DaisyLiang what do you mean?